# Cast type not work in generic function scope. Why?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, generics, casting

I did a class Router (subclass of `UINavigationController`) in my project for centralize and minimize the code used to instantiate and navigate between views. But when i try minimize a particular function (`buildView`), the type casting not work. But this works fine out of scope of function `buildView`, same whithout the `as!` operator in function `goHome`.

```
enum Routes {
    case home
    case account

    var file: String {

        switch self {
        case .home:
            return "HomeView"
        case .account:
            return "AccountView"
    }
}

protocol HomeInterface: class {

    func goTo(view: Routes)
    func showModal(view: Routes, caller: UIViewController)
}

class HomePresenter: NSObject, HomeInterface {
    init(view: HomeViewInterface) {

        self.view = view
    }
    internal func goTo(view: Routes) { /* Implementation */ }
    internal func showModal(view: Routes, caller: UIViewController) {/* Implementation */ }
}


protocol HomeViewInterface: class { 
/* Implementation */
}

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, HomeViewInterface {

        var presenter: HomeInterface?

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        }
    /* Implementation */
}
```

Working Code

```
    func goHome() {

        let viewInstance = buildView(view.file, HomeViewController.identifier, HomeViewController.self)

        viewInstance.presenter = HomePresenter(view: viewInstance)
        self.view?.pushViewController(viewInstance, animated: true)
    }

    private func buildView<T>(_ nameFile: String, _ identifier: String, _ viewClass: T.Type) -> T {

        return UIStoryboard(name: nameFile, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as! T
    }
```

Desired final code, but does not work:

```
func goHome() { 
    buildViewFinal(view.file, HomeViewController.identifier, HomeViewController.self)
}

func buildViewFinal<T, P>(_ nameFile: String, _ identifier: String, viewClass: T, presenter: P) {

    let viewInstance = UIStoryboard(name: nameFile, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as? T

    viewInstance.presenter = P(view: viewInstance)
    self.view?.pushViewController(viewInstance, animated: true)
}
```

When i try minimize the code only to `buildViewFinal`function, the property `presenter` of `viewInstance` is not recognize, showing a compile error

> Value of type 'T?' has no member 'presenter'

, and in `pushViewController`show error:

> Cannot convert value of type 'T?' to expected element type
>   'UIViewController'

The main goal is turn all code to create and navigate useful and simple.

So, how this works fine in first code, but fails in recognize type inside `buildViewFinal` scope?

Comment: What is presenter?

Comment: What is the type of `viewInstance.presenter`? Can you show the declaration of that type?

Comment: Presenter declaration added

Comment: enum `Routes` added

Comment: Which class defines the `presenter` property?

Comment: `presenter` property is defined by `protocol HomeInterface`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first piece of code, you are passing `HomeViewController.self` as `viewClass` and so it knows that `buildViewFinal` is going to return an instance of `HomeViewController` and that `HomeViewController` has a `presenter` property.

In the second code snippet, the compiler doesn't know anything about `T`, so it can't assume that it will have a `presenter` property.

You could use type constraint to enforce that `T` is a `HomeViewController` or whatever class defines the `presenter` property:

```
func buildViewFinal<T: HomeInterface, P>(_ nameFile: String, _ identifier: String, viewClass: T, presenter: P) {

    let viewInstance = UIStoryboard(name: nameFile, bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: identifier) as? T

    viewInstance.presenter = P(view: viewInstance)
    self.view?.pushViewController(viewInstance, animated: true)
}
```

but then you will have a problem that `viewInstance` can't be pushed because the compiler doesn't know that it is an instance of a `UIViewController` subclass.

Really generics and protocols are just complicating things here.

You are dealing with UIKit which is class oriented, so you might as well just use good old inheritance

Comment: Thanks! This approach is good. I'll refactor and consider your observation.